# Azure Data Factory API call details in POSTMAN

Tags: azure, postman, azure-data-factory

I am trying to use the WEB Activity from ADF to call an API. We used Postman to test this API that returns an AUTH TOKEN but I'm not sure how can I replicate the written Authorizations in ADF Web Activity.

[image]

I believe this is the same as the what is shown in ADF here.
I'm not sure what is the corresponding Authentication I need to use here as the same as in Postman.

[image]

and as for the body it is formatted as  x-wwww-form-urlencoded

[image]

If I'm going to convert this to JSON or type where I can put this in ADF Web activity Body field, is it the same as this?

```
{
     "client_id": "1234",
     "client_secret": "abcd123",
     "grant_type": "client_credentials"

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have **Client ID** and **Client Secret**, you can generate the access token in ADF web activity like below.

Give the URL like this:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/token
```

Pass the body like this:

```
grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=<your-client-id>&client_secret=<your-client-secret>
```

Set the Authentication to None and start the web activity.

[image]

You can see that I am able to generate the access token.

[image]

You can use this access token later to get the data from your API.